# setFont for UIButton is deprecated, I tried new method but keep failed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I want to customise all my buttons with my own font using this code :

```
// Custom fonts for button with tag
for (UIButton *customButton in [[self view] subviews]) {
    if (customButton.tag == 1) {
        customButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Regular" size:14];
    }
}
```

but I got this error message on my debugger console :

```
2013-09-21 00:33:33.160 Test[794:907] -[UILabel titleLabel]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1dda8d80
2013-09-21 00:33:33.165 Test[794:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UILabel titleLabel]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1dda8d80'
```

what did I do wrong? I'm using XCode 4.6.3 and targeting iOS6. thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object which you sending message `titleLabel` is not `UIButton`, it'a already `UILabel` with tag = 1, you need to make sure, that you accessing `UIButton` object:

```
for (UIButton *customButton in [[self view] subviews]) {
    if ((customButton.tag == 1) && ([customButton isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])) {
        customButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Regular" size:14];
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, bro!! it's working... you're right about this `&& ([customButton isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]))`

Answer (score 1):

This means, that customButton is not a button, it s a UILabel. UILabel got no titleLabel, this is why you got this error. Check if .tag == 1 and its class is UIButton. If it is you can change the font, as you did .

Answer (score 1):

This question has already been asked, so I'll just quote the answer from the other thread.

"
If you use IBOutletCollection then this should be direct.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *buttons;
```

Connect the buttons to this outlet collection and later alter the font in a single shot using,

```
[self setValue:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:30] forKeyPath:@"buttons.font"];
```

"

And that will change all of the button's fonts that are connected to the IBOutletCollection

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
[button.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13]];
```